# UTF-8 Encoding with lxml.html

Tags: python, unicode, lxml

How would I capture the proper encoding from a Japanese synopsis from Google Play? Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
res=requests.get('https://play.google.com/store/tv/show?id=bgJpf84fT4Q')
node=html.fromstring(res.content)
print node.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]')[0].text
```

æ¥æ¬ã®ã©ããã«å­å¨ããå¶æªãªç¯ç½ªãå¤çºããç¡æ³å°å¸¯ãéç§°ãæ··æ²è¡ï¼ã«ã¼ãªã¹ã¿ã¦ã³ï¼ããè­¦å¯ããè¦æ¾ãããã®è¡ã«ãç¯ç½ªèããæããããç¾èã®å¥³æ®ºãå±ãã¡ãå­å¨ãã...ãã®åããã¢ã·ãã¬ãï¼ã¢ãã«ã¬ã¼ã«ãºï¼ããã­ã£ãã¬ã¼ã»ã¢ã·ãã¬ãããã¯ãè¡¨åãã¯ç¾èã®è¸ãå­ãã¡ãéãéå ´ã ããè£ã®é¡ã¯æªã¸ã®å¾©è®ãæãèãã¢ã·ãã¬ã«æ®ºããä¾é ¼ããå ´æãå¼·ãçµæåãããããã§ããªããã°ãä¾é ¼äººã«ææç§»å¥ããããã§ããªããéããç©ã¾ããã°ã©ããªç¸æã§ããèªæ¢ã®ç¾èã§ã¯ã¼ã«ï¼ã»ã¯ã·ã¼ã«ãããã¦å¿ãä»çããã®ã ...ãã­ã£ãã¬ã¼ã®çµå¶èã»ã¿ã³ã½ã¯ããå¨¼å©¦ã»ãã³ã½ã¯ãã¯ããã¨ããåæ§çãªã­ã£ã©ã¯ã¿ã¼ã¨ã¨ãã«ãä»æ¥ãã

How can I set utf-8 encoding on the `text` property?

Comment: If you're using `requests`, why not use `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: @Kupiakos I just find it a bit easier to parse the xpath from lxml. This is the first time I've run into this encoding issue with non-latin characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `res.text`, not `res.content`. The former is an already-decoded `unicode`. The latter is a not-yet-decoded `str`.

```
node=html.fromstring(res.text)
```

Second, there isn't a `<div itemprop="description">` on that page. The only `itemprop="description"` I could find is in a `<meta>`, not a `<div>`, as revealed by:

```
print [n.tag for n in node.xpath('//*[@itemprop="description"]')]
```

Comment: Thank you. Here is what I'm seeing: <div class="show-more-content text-body" `itemprop="description">` Arman has given up all his pleasures and vices: smoking, drinking and fast food and he's gone through an initial extreme combat arts training period of six months. Now Arman travels to 10 exotic countries around the world, including Japan, China, USA, Cambodia and Malaysia -- each a birthplace of a different martial art! He has to learn vital combat skills, extreme discipline and extreme suffering! ...s?  <div class="show-more-end"></div> </div>

Comment: also, what's the different between `res.text` and `res.url` ?

Comment: I see the `<div class="show-more-content text-body" itemprop="description">` when I use Chrome's dev console, but not when I use `requests`. I wonder if that `div` is synthesized by the Javascript, or perhaps different data is returned based on user-agent.

Comment: got it, thank you for the clarification in the updated answer.